# May I ask how to present the backtest result by by vertorbt (From_Signal) or backtesting.py with abosulte point but not in percentage?

Tags: python, algorithm, trading, back-testing, vectorbt

May I ask how to present the backtest result by by vertorbt (From_Signal) or backtesting.py with abosulte point but not in percentage? Say, I am trading index futures, so I have a fixed gain for each point instead of being a relative equity.

Algorithm Trading with Python

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.